# MYSQL join 3rd table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MYSQL

```
SELECT T2.name as username, T2.id as userid, 
       T2.lastactivity as lastactivity, T2.photo as avatar
FROM exchange AS T2
  INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT (CASE WHEN `buddy`.`penpalA` = 887 
                     THEN `buddy`.`penpalB` 
                     ELSE `buddy`.`penpalA` 
              END) AS 'friend'
      FROM `buddy`
      WHERE status = 1 AND `penpalA` = 887
         OR `penpalB` = 887
    ) AS _Temp 
    ON _Temp.friend = T2.`id`
```

How do I add another table to it in order to get other details where __Temp.friend and now T3.userid are the common denominators

Comment: Congratulations? Is there a question in all that?

Comment: @JakeStainer so what's your question?

Comment: how do i add another table to the join and get details from another table where the userid is linked to it

Comment: (unrelated): I think the `WHERE` may need parenthesis: `status = 1 AND (penpalA = 887 OR penpalB = 887)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT T2.name as username, T2.id as userid, 
           T2.lastactivity as lastactivity, T2.photo as avatar,T3.*
    FROM exchange AS T2
      INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT (CASE WHEN `buddy`.`penpalA` = 887 
                         THEN `buddy`.`penpalB` 
                         ELSE `buddy`.`penpalA` 
                  END) AS 'friend'
          FROM `buddy`
          WHERE status = 1 AND `penpalA` = 887
             OR `penpalB` = 887
        ) AS _Temp 
        ON _Temp.friend = T2.`id`
     LEFT JOIN details T3 ON _Temp.friend=T3.UserId
```

Comment: hi, im only getting results where the userid actually exists in T3, i need it so that if nothing is in T3 then it just shows blanks

Comment: I changed the final JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, which should do what you want...